# Google Chrome extension iMacros for Chrome will not start

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, imacros

I installed "iMacros for Chrome" as an extension for my Google Chrome web browser on Windows 7.  I used the extension happily for a few months.  Then, strangely, one day, I was unable to click the toolbutton.  Literally, it shows to the right of my omnibar, but left clicking does nothing.  I can right click to activate a context menu (that works OK), so I know the extension is installed.

Also, in the Chrome Extensions management console, the extension is enabled and I have checked "Allow access to file URLs".

Could this extension be blocked by a Windows security policy?